# The $f(x)$ that minimizes $g(f(x))$ asymptotically

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Assume $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and $a,b>0$. Find the $f(x)$ that yields the lowest order for
$$g(x)=\ln f(x) + \frac{a x}{b+\ln(1+f(x))}$$
as $x\to\infty$.
By *order* I mean [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [Little o](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Little-o_notation) notation.

I can only solve it roughly:

**My solution**: Since $f(x)\to\infty$, $\ln(1+f(x)) \approx\ln(f(x))$. Then, I have to minimize the order of $b+\ln f(x) + \frac{a x}{b+\ln f(x)}$. Since for any $c>0$, $y+c/y$ is miminized when $y =\sqrt{c}$, the following $f(x)$ should satisfy ${b+\ln f(x)}=\sqrt{ax}$. Therefore,
$$f(x)=e^{\sqrt{ax}-b}$$
and the lowest order for $g(x)$ is $2\sqrt{ax}$.

Can you help me obtain a rigorous answer?